# How to export the first field of a record?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

```
"Name" : "StackOverFlow",
"Status" : "ACTIVE",
"langData" : {
    "en" : {
        "sName" : "xyz",
        "sAdr1" : "abc",
    },
    "cn" : {
        "sName" : "pqr",
        "sAdr1" : "lmn",
    }
}
```

I have a mongo db collection, with the sample data pasted above.
I am trying to extract some data out of the collection using mongoexport.

**Command**:

```
./mongoexport --host <host> --port <port> --username <name> --password <password> \
              --collection <collectionname> --db <dbname> --out output.csv \
              --query "{'Name':'StackOverFlow'}" \
              --fields Status,langData.en.sName \
              --csv
```

The above command is giving me the required data from collection.

What I need to know is, if there is a way by which I can extract the data, if I am not aware of subcollection, i.e en or cn. What I want is to get the first sub-document data.

I tried using the following query, but it didnt work:

```
./mongoexport --host <host> --port <port> --username <name> --password <password> \
              --collection <collectionname> --db <dbname> --out output.csv \
              --query "{'Name':'StackOverFlow'}" \
              --fields Status,langData.0.sName \
              --csv
```

Comment: If langData were an array, langData.0.sName would have worked. Unfortunately it is a document

Comment: As a complement of @ZeMonn's comment, strictly speaking there is no such thing as _"the first sub-document"_ as you store your sub-documents as fields of an object -- not as items in an array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question: there is no possible answer because the data model is incompatible with what you are trying to achieve

Comment: There is nothing i can do with the Data Model, this is how i got.I was looking for an option to get the required data, assuming there are no viable options.

Comment: I agree with Sylvain, @Chittprakash . Data modelling in MongoDB works differently: You model your data according to your use cases and the given technical constraints instead of modeling according to your entities and ask your questions according to the technical constraints.

Comment: If the data export you want to achieve isn't possible with `mongoexport`, you can always write a small program in a language with a supported MongoDB driver. Almost every language should have a module for exporting to CSV, but if your example isn't overly simplified you could also just print out the few fields you need.